# part arraylist to 3 strings part

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to split my `arrayList` which has the size `3n` to 3 part (with size n each),
but I am getting just the first one. How can I fix that?

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  ==> [1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]
```

I appreciate any help.

```
List<RootCreator> mainSublist = new ArrayList<RootCreator>();
int number = mainList.size()/3;
for(int i= 0 ; i < mainList.size()/3; i++){
    int index = i*3 ;           
    List<RootCreator> sublist =  mainList.subList(0, index);
    mainSublist.addAll(sublist);
}
```

Comment: Can you reword your question so that it unambiguously clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I have added a simple to clarify it.

Comment: Where do you want to store these 3 separate `List`s?  It appears that you only have one place for your result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: in this arrayList<String> `mainSublist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) like this -

```
static <T> List<List<T>> split(List<T> list, int n) {

    List<List<T>> parts = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    int size = list.size();

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index += n) {
        parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(
            list.subList(index, Math.min(size, index + n)))
        );
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<RootCreator> mainSublist = mainList.subList(0, mainList.size() / 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem: you always call mainList.subList() with first argument 0.

```
    List<RootCreator> mainSublist = new ArrayList<RootCreator>();
    int number = mainList.size()/3;
    int first = 0;
    for(; first < mainList.size() - number; first+=number){
        mainSublist.addAll(mainList.subList(first, first + number));
    }
    mainSublist.addAll(mainList.subList(first));
```

Comment: The last line cannot be compiled.